Make AWS Vulnerability scanner scan only code, not dependencies in pom.xml
Please help me make AWS scanner not to scan dependencies in pom.xml file which are not in real production code. For instance, I have tons of log4j vulnerabilities but no log4j code or library in  the program code. It took this from pom.xml file, just text, how to avoid that? May be create suppression rule, but I failed to do that, how to say not to scan pom files in dependency jars.

